# How to get ID of the currently viewing Product in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a list of products(images) which users can scroll(I do it using Jquery) & their is id associated with each image, I want if user click on the button(add to cart) then the product should be add to the cart. I don't know how to get the ID of currently displaying product. Please help i am new to MVC.

View

  // images here

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Product"))
{
    <input type=submit value="Add To Cart"/>
}
```

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyUsers user)
    {
        string s = user.Name;
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Use get method. Sample: /cart/add/<prdcID>

Comment: Do you want to have 1 add to cart button for all of products?

Answer (score 1):

If there is a button "Add to chart" associated with each product, add a hidden field with appropriate product ID next to each of these buttons.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Product"))
{
    @Html.Hidden("ProductID", productID)
    <input type="submit" value="Add To Cart"/>
}
```

Then add parameter ProductID to the action method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyUsers user, int productID)
{
    // Your code...
}
```

Comment: but what if user swipe the product image, then

Comment: according to the comment under your original question, you want to have only one submit button and you select pictures somehow using jQuery. then you can change the value of the hidden field using jQuery too.

Comment: [HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyUsers user, int productID)
{
    // Your code...
} but the value here of productID is always null, y it is always null

Answer (score 0):

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{ 
    foreach(Product product in Model)
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(model => product.Name)
        @Html.ActionLink("Add To Cart", "Add", "Product", new { id = product.Id })
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Add(int id)   
{   
    // Your code...   
}
```